# Strange error with changed class name in Java

Tags: java, jira, jira-plugin, kryo

I am using kryo lib to serialize objects. I get error:

```
Unable to find class: java.util.ArrayLisoSerialization
```

and teammates reproduce that error... It seems that java class name from Kryo was changed (ArrayListSerialization -> ArrayLisoSerialization). That was tested at 2 computers (linux and windows, both jdk7) and problem appears only on my computer (linux). I tried to change Java version from jdk7 (build 67) to jdk8, but problem still appears.

Any ideas why it happens?

Bigger part of error trace:

```
com.esotericsoftware.kryo.KryoException: Unable to find class: java.util.ArrayLisoSerialization trace:messages  at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.util.DefaultClassResolver.readName(DefaultClassResolver.java:138)  at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.util.DefaultClassResolver.readClass(DefaultClassResolver.java:115) at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readClass(Kryo.java:666)  at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.ObjectField.read(ObjectField.java:99)  at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer.read(FieldSerializer.java:528) at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readObject(Kryo.java:682)...
```

Answer (score 0):

That looks like a typo somewhere in kryo or in a configuration file in your project.
I would do a string search on your project file first.

On second glance, this is going wrong:

```
String className = input.readString();
....
type = Class.forName(className, false, kryo.getClassLoader());
```

The problem is in your data it sees. Your serialized content contains, as className, the wrong class you mention.

I don't know how this could've been caused to write like this, as I would assume that a java.util.ArrayListSerialization was originally written but got corrupted somehow.

I'm not too familiar with Kryo however. Is this written to a human readable text file? if so this might've been an accidental replacement while reading the file by hand. (with vi, notepad, or something else). From what I can see, the inputstream is simply read, and a string is opened.

I would open the data file and see if the string java.util.ArrayLisoSerialization is present there. 
I assume this should be changed to java.util.ArrayListSerialization.

**HOWEVER** make a backup of any data you are modifying. Changing serialized data should always be done with the safety of being able to revert back to the original data.

Comment: I tried to find typo in my project, but there are no errors. Kryo is open source project, so I will check their project for any typo errors

Comment: @ElSzarry updated my answer. I went through the entire stacktrace and the LisoSerialization clearly comes out of the input stream. so either a file on disk or blob in database contains the wrong value.

Comment: I can't find any errors. After I installed Windows on Virtual box, error doesn't appear. I don't know what is a problem, but I think that can be placed in my linux's enviroment. Thanks for your help Joeblade :)